# generate_series in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, postgresql, generate-series

What is the PostgreSQL's `generate_series()` equivalent in MySQL?

How to convert this query to MySQL?

```
select substr('some-string', generate_series(1, char_length('some-string')))
```

Sample output from PostgreSQL:

```
some-string
ome-string
me-string
e-string
-string
string
tring
ring
ing
ng
g

select generate_series(1, char_length('some-string'))

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

#### Final solution:

```
CREATE TABLE `numberlist` (
 `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `numberlist` values(null)
(repeat the above query the maximum string you need)

SELECT substr('somestring', id) 
FROM numberlist 
WHERE id <= character_length('somestring')
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the output of above in PostgreSQL?   I think I know and have a way it should work in mySQL, but want to see your expected output before suggesting an answer.   Thanks

Comment: Do series generate in reverse like that?  I would have thought it would start with g, then ng, then ing, etc...

Comment: @Sparky, copied the exact output. But I think order does not matter in my case, I just need the patterns.

Comment: `generate_series` just generates integers in order. You're seeing `substr`'s behavior.

Comment: @Daniel, Right, I've added another example.

Comment: You would have to write a stored procedure that returns a resultset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the concept, but I don't have mySQL installed on this box.   You will need to create a table of integers, using AUTO INCREMENT.  A table of numbers is generally a handy table to have available in a database, and would only need be created once

```
create table NumberList (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,fill char(1))

declare @x INT
set @x=0
while @x < 20
begin
    insert into numberList values(null)
    Set @x = @x+1
end
```

Then, join this table as shown below using the LIMIT clause

```
select substr('somestring',id) 
from numberlist
limit len('somestring')
```

I wrote this in SQL server, but it shouldn't be too difficult to convert to mySQL...

The code below SHOULD work in mySQL

```
DECLARE xx INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE xx < 20 DO
    insert into numberList values(null)        
    SET xx = xx + 1;
 END WHILE;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `DECLARE`, `SET` or `WHILE`.

Comment: @Daniel mysql *does* have set eg `set somevar := 0;`

Comment: Thanks guys, I've been working in MS SQL so much lately, but hope the SQL is close enough it can be easily converted...

Comment: Does it have `WHILE` somewhere I haven't seen? If not, this isn't going to work.

Comment: @Sparky This declare does not work on MySQL. But I inserted the data manually. The next thing is that the correct function name to determine length is: `char_length`, but this does not work in `limit`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now, but it looks like you created a workable solution...